# Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, frontend

i dont know why i get this error. It is in AppComponent.html:4

> Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

**app.component.html**

```
<h2>Movies</h2>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor='let movie of movies'>
    <h2>{{movie.title}}</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ApiService} from './api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [ApiService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  movies = [{title: 'test'}];

  constructor(private api: ApiService) {
    this.getMovies();
  }

  getMovies = () => {
    this.api.getAllMovies().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.movies = data;
      },
      error1 => {
        console.log('error');
      }
    );
  };
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ApiService { 

baseurl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"; httpHeader = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {} 

getAllMovies(): Observable<any>
{ 
    return this.http.get(this.baseurl + '/movies/', {headers: this.httpHeader});
} 


}
```

Can you tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: **api.service.ts**
`import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {


  baseurl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
  httpHeader = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAllMovies(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.baseurl + '/movies/',
      {headers: this.httpHeader});
  }

} `

Comment: Can you add `console.log(data)` inside your getAllMovies subscribe and report the result of it?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/c99ruGn same

Comment: By showing the results I meant from the browser dev console.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/CMrtFI9 @alt255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `*ngFor` you can only use arrays / iterables, what I can imagine is happening here is your API call is returning an object. You should find a way to change this to an array for your existing template to work. Providing what your response looks like should help with that.

For the mean while what you could do is use the [keyvalue pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe). Which would make your code look like so.

```
<h2>Movies</h2>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor='let movie of movies | keyvalue'>
    <h2>{{movie.title}}</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**After JSON was added**

looking at the picture of your JSON (please try and use snippets rather than images) you could have. This means the above solution would not work amazingly but is something to remember as its useful for certain scenarios.

```
<h2>Movies</h2>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor='let movie of movies.results'>
    <h2>{{movie.title}}</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As the documentation will show, this will allow you to use `*ngfor` with an object as opposed to an array. This is part of commonModule.

Comment: its not worked, i changed in app.component.ts change this.movies = data; to this.movies = data.results; and its worked 

i was doint tutorial from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_H-oxQVsPw and guy in video doesnt have to make like me, and its worked anyway dont know why

Comment: Yes,  this.movies = data.results; or the above would work :-)